# Uninstall ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: uninstall, system

I want to replace 32 bit with 64 bit.  How do I unintstall ubuntu 14.04.2 32 bit desktop so as to replace it with ubuntu 14.04.3 64 bit desktop.  Note that this is the only operating system on the drive and that no backup will be required since I have not yet added any personal files or other information.

Comment: As suggested by biozalp, I now have ubuntu 14.04.3 64 bit on USB using start up disk.  Keep in mind that 14.04.2 is still my operating system.  Since I can't remove it, I assume by installing 14.04.3 (64) from USB will overwrite the existing 14.04.2 (32).  Is this correct?  If so, how do I change the boot order to look at  the  USB drive first?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, download 64bit iso from Ubuntu website, burn it in to a usb via Startup Disk Creator, boot and follow the standart installation

This should not be a problem since you've not added personal files yet.

I assume you have a  fully functional system right now